# Array of Column Variables in SQL

Tags: sql, arrays, variables, sas

Is it possible to create an array of column variables within sql to perform an operation like the following (please excuse the syntax):

```
array(Col1,Col2,Col3);

update tempTable
    for(i=1;i<3;i++){
        set array[i] = 
            case missing(array[i]) 
                then 0*1
            else
                array[i]*1
            end
};
```

note: I am using a proc SQL step in SAS

Desired function:
Perform the operation in the for loop above on multiple columns of a table, without writing a separate set statement for each column.

Comment: Why use SQL for this? Why not just write a normal DATA step?

Comment: Making an effort to learn SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS Macros write SAS code for you.  They are pre-compiler scripts that generate SAS Code.

You want code that looks like

```
update table
   set col1 = ...  ,
       col2 = ...  ,
       ....        ,
   ;
```

Here is a script.  It generates a test table, defines the macro, and then calls the macro on the table.  It uses the `sum()` function from my other answer.

```
data have;
array col[3];

do r=1 to 100;
    do i=1 to 3;
        if ranuni(123)> .8 then
            col[i] = .;
        else
            col[i] = rannor(123);
    end;
    output;
end;
drop i r;
run;

%macro sql_zero_if_missing(data, cols);
%local n i col;
%let n=%sysfunc(countw(&cols));

proc sql noprint;
update &data
    set
    %do i=1 %to &n;
        %let col=%scan(&cols,&i);
        &col = sum(&col,0)
        %if &i ^= &n %then , ;
    %end;
;
quit;

%mend;

options mprint;
%sql_zero_if_missing(have, col1 col2 col3);
```

The `MPRINT` option will let you see the SAS code that was generated.  Here is the log:

> MPRINT(SQL_ZERO_IF_MISSING):   proc sql noprint;
>
> MPRINT(SQL_ZERO_IF_MISSING):   update have set col1 = sum(col1,0) ,
>   col2 = sum(col2,0) , col3 = sum(col3,0) ;
>
> NOTE: 100 rows were updated
>   in WORK.HAVE.
>
> MPRINT(SQL_ZERO_IF_MISSING):   quit;

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do what you are looking for with a SAS macro.

It is easier, if this is a local SAS table, to just update it with the Data Step.

```
data have;
set have;
array v[3] col1 col2 col3;

do i=1 to 3;
    v[i] = sum(v[i],0);
end;

drop i;
run;
```

The `sum()` function sums values (obviously).  If a value is missing, it is not added and the remaining values are added.  So you will get 0 in the case of missing and the value of the column when it is not.

Comment: Thanks! However is it possible to do this using SQL?

Comment: Not easily. You could write a macro to basically create the multiple SQL codes though, just not usually worth the effort.